# DoJo on Wordpress 4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dojo

**SOLUTION:** For everyone interested: turned out the solution was moving all files that use DoJo beneath the jQuery UI files, so that jQuery UI is fully loaded before any DoJo stuff loads. Moved them all in the footer in that order (jQuery, then jQuery UI and then alle DoJo related files).

*Still wondering though why this has been an issue in WP 4.1, while it worked perfectly without the fix in WP 4.0.*

I'm running a Wordpress [website](https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/) which uses both jQuery and DoJo (part of the ArcGIS JS API, loaded from http://js.arcgis.com/3/12/). 
After recently upgrading from Wordpress 4.0.1 to 4.1, things broke.
Dojo is returning multiple Error: multipleDefine errors.

Basically it looks like DoJo tries to load a new instance of jQuery, which it shouldn't, since WordPress has loaded jQuery already and there isn't a jQuery module available in the DoJo map. Furthermore, this issues seems to only exists in WordPress, not in a jsfiddle I made including exactly the same scripts.

For debugging purposes I first disabled all WordPress plugins, without any result; the problem kept existing. I went on and found a couple of interesting things. But I'm really stuck in the further debugging proces. I know the scope of this question is rather broad, but any thoughts at all are very much appreciated.

*What I know so far/that i'm wondering about:*

-Things stopt working after upgrading to WordPress 4.1

-In the info of the multipleDefine error it states https://js.arcgis.com/3.11/jquery.js, which is weird: it shouldn't be looking for jQuery there, since it's already included in Wordpress

-Things break as soon as I included the ArcGIS Javascript API, which includes DoJO

-In addition: leaving WordPress out still gives trouble in this jsfiddle, although dojo isn't looking for jQuery right now http://jsfiddle.net/dhunink/mry5vn3s/8/

```
<script>
  var dojoConfig = { 
    isDebug: true,
    async: false
  };
</script>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
```

[image][image]The things mentioned above leads me to the conclusion that something changed in the last WordPress release that effects my script, although I can't find anything in the release notes that could be linked to my issue.

Any thoughts, suggestions of comments are highly appreciated! Feel free to see all in action at https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/.

Comment: Did you try the wp-reinstall button, or diff the output of the page with 4.0 vs 4.1?

Comment: @NoBugs got it fixed now, see the edit in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** For everyone interested: turned out the solution was moving all files that use DoJo beneath the jQuery UI files, so that jQuery UI is fully loaded before any DoJo stuff loads. Moved them all in the footer in that order (jQuery, then jQuery UI and then alle DoJo related files).

*Still wondering though why this has been an issue in WP 4.1, while it worked perfectly without the fix in WP 4.0.*